# Autocomplete jquery cannot print suggestions

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jsonp

I have created with python a function that returns this:

```
 callback({"query": "can", "suggestions": "['Cane','Canal','Candy','Canis','Canoe','Canada','Canary','Canola','Cantil','Decane','Toucan','Candida','Candiru','Candoia','Canidae','Cannula','Indican','Pelican','Scanner','Acanthis','']", "data": "['Cane','Canal','Candy','Canis','Canoe','Canada','Canary','Canola','Cantil','Decane','Toucan','Candida','Candiru','Candoia','Canidae','Cannula','Indican','Pelican','Scanner','Acanthis','']"});
```

I am trying to use autocomplete of devbridge https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

I managed to get the list with ajax like this:

```
   $.ajax({ 
     url: url, 
     dataType:"jsonp",
     jsonpCallback: 'callback',

     success: function(data) { 
        alert(data.suggestions);

             } 
    });
```

But I cannot make it work with autocomplete. I changed my functions return into callback because I had problem with cross-domain url and also this is why I used jsonp. I also tried to add data.suggestions into an array

```
             var availableTags =   data.suggestions;
             var stri = availableTags.replace(/["']/g, "");
             availableTags = stri.replace("[","");
             stri = availableTags.replace("]","");
             suggestionsArray = stri.split(",");
```

and print it in jquery like this:

```
 $( "#query" ).autocomplete({
  lookup: suggestionsArray
});
```

but it is not working. If I create it by hand

```
var suggestionsArray = ["cane","Canal"]
```

it is working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you mentioned shows two ways of giving data-source to the autocomplete object.

You want AJAX, so you should use it that way. The relevant example from the site:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/countries',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

So you should not use the lookup property when initialazing the autocomplete, but you should initialize the serviceUrl property.
This will handle the AJAX call as well, you don't have to care about that.

In your returned JSON string, you also need to make sure that the data.suggestions array is contains array elements, which elements should have a value and a data property.

Comment: I created the array as you said but it still wont prin in autocomplete. So I think the problem is somewhere else